# Sending/Receiving data fast over TCP causes block

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm testing my servers performance by creating 4 clients. Then they send 1 packet per second to the server, the server then receives these packets and sends them to the other clients.

My server is setup on a Linux virtual box on the same machine. Data is successfully sent and received for about 20 seconds then everything pauses and no more data can be sent or received? is this because I am filling up some sort of TCP queue? if I am is there some software I can use to see how full the queue is?

When I then close these clients the server runs and accepts messages.

Comment: We need to know rather more about this setup than the information you've provided.  For starters, what is the rate of packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless everybody is reading all the data being sent to them, this will eventually stall due to TCP buffering. Only reading or closing the socket clears the buffers.

Comment: Ok, so my test connections are not receiving data they are only sending it.. Wouldn't that just result in the packets being lost? Is there away to avoid that? Else couldn't some random person just spam connections and flood sends with no receives to break anyone's server?

Comment: No, it results in the data being buffered. I've already said that. TCP doesn't just lose data.

Comment: I don't understand - whay are you test connections only sending data?  Why are they not receiving it?  You seem to have violated your own design, (though it's true that you should design your server to correctly handle clients that misbehave).

Comment: Yeah sorry EJP I understand you. Just didn't explain myself correctly. Don't know why I said that post. Is there a way to disconnect a user if he is not receiving? Martin James the clients will be receiving in the end but I want to make sure some malicious cannot deadlock my server :)